# How do I get the date value from react-datepicker to register of the react-hook-form

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hook-form

I'm making a registration form with required birthday field using react-datepicker and react-hook-form.
After clicking onSubmit button, all data are logged in the console except birthDate (which is null). How do I get the date value from react-datepicker to register of the react-hook-form?

RegistrationForm interface

```
export interface RegistrationForm {
  username: string;
  birthDate: Date;
  email: string;
  password: string;
  passwordConfirm: string;
}
```

```
const {register, handleSubmit, formState: {errors}, watch, control } = useForm<RegistrationForm>()

const onSubmit = async (data: RegistrationForm) => {
            console.log(data)
}

const [selectedBirthDate, setSelectedBirthDate] = useState<Date>(new Date()) 
      
      const handleDateChange = (date: Date | null) => {
            if(date != null)  {
                  setSelectedBirthDate(date)
            }
      }
```

In my Controller tag

```
                             <Controller
                                    name={"birthDate"}
                                    control={control}
                                    defaultValue={selectedBirthDate}
                                    render={({field}) => {
                                          return(
                                                <DatePicker
                                                      onChange={(date: Date) => handleDateChange(date)}
                                                      selected={selectedBirthDate}
                                                      placeholderText="Enter your birth date"
                                                />
                                          )
                                    }}
                              />
```

Username form

```
                              <input 
                                    type="text" 
                                    placeholder="username" 
                                    {...register("username", {
                                          required: true, 
                                          maxLength: 20,
                                          minLength: 5 
                                    })}
                              />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to link your `<Controller />` with the `<DatePicker />` component. So it is important to use at least `value` and `onChange` and pass it to the `<DatePicker />` props.

```
<Controller
  name={"birthDate"}
  control={control}
  defaultValue={new Date()}
  render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => {
    return (
      <DatePicker
        onChange={onChange}
        selected={value}
        placeholderText="Enter your birth date"
      />
    );
  }}
/>
```

If you use RHF you also don't need `useState` to handle your state changes as RHF will handle those changes for you.

[image: Edit React Hook Form - Controller react-datepicker]

**UPDATE**

To display an error, you need the `errors` object, which RHF provides via the `formState` property. But you need to create a validation rule first: you can choose between rules provided by RHF and custom rules, see [here](https://react-hook-form.com/api/useform/register) for more info (please don't get confused, you can find the rules in the docs under `register`, because `register` and `<Controller />` have the same interface for the validation rules).

You can then add the rules using the `rules` prop from `<Controller />`. As an example, I have added a validation that checks if the selected date is older than 2 years. For displaying the error i used the `<ErrorMessage />` component provided by the package `@hookform/error-message`, but you could also just check if `errors.birthDate` exists and show your own custom error message.

```js
const sub2Years = subYears(2);

const isOlderThan2Years = (date) =>
  isBefore(sub2Years(new Date()), date) || "Date is not older than 2 years";
```

```
<Controller
  name={"birthDate"}
  control={control}
  defaultValue={new Date()}
  rules={{ validate: { isOlderThan2Years } }}
  render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => {
    return (
      <DatePicker
        onChange={onChange}
        selected={value}
        placeholderText="Enter your birth date"
      />
    );
  }}
/>
<ErrorMessage
  errors={errors}
  name="birthDate"
  render={({ message }) => <p>{message}</p>}
/>
```

[image: Edit React Hook Form - Controller react-datepicker--with-validation]

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Can you please explain or provide any online guide on how to display an error using Controller when the user selected an invalid age if react hook form?

Comment: I have updated my answer, I hope it can help as a starting point.